# Why properties doesn't show in preview?

Tags: android

This is a photo of my Android Studio.

Why properties doesn't show in preview?

[image]

Comment: Which properties? can you specify more about your problem?

Comment: which properties?

Comment: Refer this [https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor)